# docusignapi Define size of an anchor tab

Tags: docusignapi

I have a anchor tab for a signer. Is there any way to define the size of a Sign box? I tried CustomTabWidth but it does not look right.

```
<Tabs>
                <Tab>
                    <DocumentID>LEASE AGREEMENT</DocumentID>
                    <RecipientID>1</RecipientID>
                    <AnchorTabItem>
                        <AnchorTabString>??CS1!</AnchorTabString>
                        <Unit>Cms</Unit>
                        <IgnoreIfNotPresent>false</IgnoreIfNotPresent>
                    </AnchorTabItem>
                    <CustomTabWidth>5</CustomTabWidth>
                    <CustomTabWidthSpecified>True</CustomTabWidthSpecified>
                    <Type>SignHere</Type>
                    <Name>Lessee Signature 1</Name>
                </Tab>
            </Tabs>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the "scaleValue" property with a value from 0.5 to 1.0 to set the scale of the tab.  This corresponds with how you can resize tabs in the UI.